# Can not find a Key deserializer when mapping key is null

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

After going through similar questions, I am not still able to solve this problem. I am using `Jackson` to serialize and deserialize class that does not have matching getters/setters method.

```
public class Products implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@JsonProperty
private final Map<Product, String> prices;

public Products() {
    this.prices = new HashMap<>();
}

public void addPrice(final Product product, final String price) {
    prices.put(product, price);
}
}
```

Product Class:

```
public class Product implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@JsonProperty
private final String name;
@JsonProperty
private final String type;

public Product(final String price, final String type) {
    this.name = price;
    this.type = type;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Products products = new Products();
    products.addPrice(new Product("apple", "fruit"), "16");

    JsonDataConverter converter = new JsonDataConverter();
    String json = converter.toData(products);
    System.out.println(json);

    Products deserializedProducts = converter.fromData(json, Products.class);
}
}
```

`JsonDataConverter` I am using is from `AWS Flow Framework`: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/simpleworkflow/flow/JsonDataConverter.html

Exception I am getting at deserialization step is: `Can not find a (Map) Key deserializer for type [simple type, class mypackage.Product] when mapping key "null"`.

I am not able to understand this since my `prices` map does not contain any null values. Strange thing is, It's working fine if `Product` has only 1 member (just `name`) field.

Any idea what's is going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: It looks like the problem is that your Products map has a composite key. Jackson needs to know how to convert it to a string.

Comment: @Alexey, It might be but It serializes just fine. Also everything works fine if there is only one member in ```Product``` class. So not sure if that is the problem.

Comment: what is your desired JSON format?

Comment: I am not too worried about json format as long as it serializes and deserializes successfully.

Comment: I am also having the same issue , it serializes fine , but i am having issues while deserialization. It gives below error :-

No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class org.joda.time.chrono.ISOChronology]: can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?)

Answer (score 0):

Can u try modify the  constructor of product and products classes to have JsonCreator annotation and annotate each param with JsonProperty.

Example:

```
@JsonCreator
public Product(@JsonProperty("price") final String price, @JsonProperty("type") final String type) {
       this.name = price; this.type = type;
}
```